# Checking a script is running

Tags: shell-script, grep, ps

I have a job test.sh schedule to run every 5 mins, and another job test1.sh scheduled to run 12.30pm , @12.30 both jobs will run and is making a deadlock. So I need to check the job test.sh is running for that I am using :

```
ps -ef | grep test1.sh
```

but this seems to be true always as it produces a line for the same command.

```
  # ps -ef | grep test1.sh
team 24896   607  0 11:55 pts/11   00:00:00 test1.sh
team 24925   523  0 11:55 pts/4    00:00:00 grep test1.sh
```

how to avoid printing grep `test1.sh`?

I am very new to unix.

Thanks,
Ann

Comment: Suggestion: just fix that deadlock. If the number of shared resources is small a strict lock ordering will do the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just ignore the grep one by one of the following:-

```
ps -ef | grep test1.sh | grep -v grep
```

else:-

```
ps -ef | grep "[t]est1.sh"
```

The second one look descent and it saves lot of time.

Answer (score 4):

If you're just looking to see if it's running rather than pipe `ps` output to `grep` you could use `pgrep`. This will only output the PID of the process and be much more efficient. I am using the `-x` flag so that it does an exact name match for test1.sh

```
pgrep -x test1.sh
876
```

If you want to see the command name as well you could also use the `-l` flag.

```
pgrep -xl test1.sh
876 test1.sh
```

And if you wanted to do a partial match you could just remove the `-x`

```
pgrep -l test
876 test1.sh
877 test2.sh
888 test123.sh
8745 test.bin
```

Comment: Thank you so much. As a new user to this portal I am finding a way to appreciate all the answers I got ...

Comment: Note that as of `pgrep 3.3.4` from procps-ng the flag to show the full command has been changed to `-a` instead of `-l`.  It seems to be there already in recent Fedora and Ubuntus at the very least.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because `grep` and `ps` are launched in parallel, thus the `grep` process is matched because the target string `test1.sh` appears as its argument in `ps`. A simple but probably sub-optimal way to bypass this would be:

```
ps -ef | grep "test1.sh" | grep -v "grep"
```

The second pipe takes the output of the first and excludes lines containing a match for the string "grep".

Comment: @Ann you should credit Ashwin by accepting his answer. EDIT: actually Zachary's answer is even more efficient. It's your call though !

Comment: I am thankful for  all the answers. I am new to this portal. Is there any way I can mark this question as answered by giving credits to the replies I got.?